# Cannot source autojump script with zsh on archlinux

Tags: zsh, archlinux

[autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump) on ArchLinux for some reason is not working in `zsh`.
Although If I switch to `bash` it works fine.

```
$ sudo pacman -S autojump
```

autojump: does not work on `zsh`

```
$ source /usr/etc/profile.d/autojump.sh
$ j
zsh: command not found: j

$ source /usr/etc/profile.d/autojump.bash
$ j
zsh: command not found: j
```

autojump: works on `bash`

```
$ bash
(bash) $ source /usr/etc/profile.d/autojump.bash
(bash) $ j
autojump: ...
```

---

My environment:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh

$ zsh --version 
zsh 5.0.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
```

I use autojump on OS X with `zsh`, so it also doesn't look like a zsh specific issue to me.

Comment: In my Antergos (arch based) the autojump is placed on /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh and my oh-my-zsh had an alias for the j key. put 

[[ -s /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh ]] && . /etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh

in your ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `/usr/etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh` pushed when `autojump` is installed via `pacman`. I don't know why this is the case.

However, I performed, manual user installation and added autojump plugin in my zsh configuration that takes care of sourcing the file.

Answer (score 3):

Aren’t you supposed to use [autojump.**zsh**](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/blob/master/bin/autojump.zsh) instead?

Though from what I see the only thing `autojump.sh` is doing is sourcing `autojump.zsh` or `autojump.bash` from some place so it should work with `.sh`. Work if maintainers of arch have patched `autojump.sh`: it does not expect to find autojump in `/usr/etc`.

If it does not work with `autojump.zsh`, post the output of doing `(set -x ; source /usr/etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried above the ways,but I solved this problem by add the

```
 source ~/.autojump/etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh
```

because the I have not find the /usr/etc/profile.d/autojump.zsh

Answer (score 0):

I had repeated trouble with Autojump in ZSH regardless of sourcing the .zsh version.  I never found a decent fix and eventually chose to stick with ZSH and **stop using** Autojump.

My personal solution was to switch from Autojump to [FASD](https://github.com/clvv/fasd).  It has the same functionality of **Autojump** via the 'z' alias.  It also allows for specifically  jumping to either a file or directory.

**FASD** has been a reliable part of my ZSH setup and surpasses the functionality of Autojump.  I wrote up my experiences with FASD at greater length on my blog at [Civet.ws](http://www.civet.ws/2012/07/fasd-the-commandline-shortcuts-i-always-wanted/)